# Unable to get push notification in IOS 9 SDK with Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: push-notification, ios9.1

If anyone has worked on iOS 9 push notification then please help.  Following are the payload string which I got from server .aps:

```
{
        alert = "You got a new message from Jack";
        sound = default;
    };
```

It works fine for iOS 8 sdks but not for iOS 9

Comment: are you testing on a device for both devices?

Comment: Yes i have tested this application on both IOS 8 and IOS 9 . It works fine for IOS 8 (Alert come with sound ) but didn't work for IOS 9 . However payload string says message delivered successfully..any solution for that

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked in the device settings and everywhere relevant that, you have accepeted notifications? you're not in DoNotDisturb mode or plane mode? anything like that?

Also, do you reach the didReceiveRemoteNotification, or not at all?

Comment: Hi Zil..thanks for your reply....i have accepted notifications and also checked relevant settings for the purpose of receiving notification . But in iOS 9 versions.. code never goes to didReceiveRemoteNotification